# How to implement an animation effect?

Tags: animation, winapi

On Windows platform, with Windows sdk, how to do some effect like the blur effect? The expend / collapse / scroll effect and so on.

My major ideal is timer combine with gdi paintings.

But the gdi painting have some problems, the action was not very smooth, compared with some other effect on the computer.

Can gdi do this or not? If so how?

I'm interested in this kind of action for a while. don't figure out how the effect has been implied.

Comment: You can use Windows UI Composition (instead of GDI) aka "Visual Layer" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/composition/visual-layer). Samples are here: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows.UI.Composition-Win32-Samples

Comment: i prefer some traditional operations, your advise seems to be a more advance method ( the .net framework , the visual layer , fancy experence.), thank you. I still remember the old version windows opertion system have the animation action, which looks more easy and cheap.

Comment: Do you want to apply these effects to a window when showing or hiding it? Is this api  [`AnimateWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-animatewindow) you want?

Comment: Animations and effects (you mention blur) that you see on Windows since Windows Vista use these technologies.